Series of short stories about hillbillies who are actually aliens
These are stories about a family or families of stereotypical hillbillies who are actually aliens with various powers. It’s semi humorous. Could be Sturgeon, Kuttner or Dick. Someone like that. From the pulp period.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

This sounds like The Hogben Chronicles, a set of short stories by Henry Kuttner, originally published in the 1940s. They tell about the adventures of a family, which seem on the surface to be hillbillies. Rather than aliens though, they are actually mutant humans, originating from the time of Roger Bacon, which, according to the stories, was when mankind first split the atom. They have a number of powers: extremely long lifespans, the ability to fly, to transmute elements, and so on. The stories are all told in a broad comedic tone.
According to a Goodreads review:

These mutant hillbilly shenanigans are quite funny and embrace a
skewed, but practical family logic. The stories "Exit the Professor,"
"Pile of Trouble, "See You Later," and "Cold War" are gems of
storytelling by a master of pulp fiction. All the stories, told from
the viewpoint of Saunk, the youngin (except for the baby in the tank),
relate various escapades keeping their family secrets while divulging
family eccentricities and their long, long history.


These may be "The People" stories by Zenna Henderson, which were originally published in "The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction" between 1952 and 1980, then also published in various collections. The stories focus on earth-human encounters with powerful and benevolent human aliens who migrated to earth during the time period when Americans were settling the western united states.
The People all have varying psychic powers: Some can locate minerals in the ground, some can form and assemble metal components, others can repair broken glass, or perform medical procedures, and they can levitate. The People went into hiding after they were persecuted as witches, and many of the stories deal with later friendly encounters between People and earthlings.
There was a 1974 TV movie, "The People" (which appears to have been filmed on the same sets as "Little House on the Prairie") that expresses the stories' themes well.


The People stories meet the first part of the query pretty well, but none of the stories could be called semi humorous,

@Mark Olson I considered that 'semi-humorous' could describe the stories' general tone, which has no laugh-out-loud humor, but is quirky and light-hearted. The People do not actually seem like 'hillbillies' either, but many of the stories are set in historical periods.

I wouldn't class The People stories as semi-humorous, but I guess they deserve an honourable mention. ;) Perhaps this answer will lead some new readers to discover these charming stories.
